Angular How to open Email as Draft (preferrably in Outlook)
We have here a frontend implemented with Angular.
Now a new requirement arisen: the frontend application should generate an Email based on HTML Templates, fill it with some data from database, add an attachment and SHOW.
Not send! Reason for this is that to some audit requirements, a particular user must review the content of the email and add some information that is known only to them (prices) and then send them manually. We use Outlook.
Is there any way to do it in Angular?
A regular email can be easily created with
window.open('mailto:$USEREMAIL?subject=Testmail&body=...', '_self');

But it seems that this way one cannot create HTML mail nor add an attachment.
Nodemailer seems to be able to do all this, but only allowing preview in the browser and is not able to send it from the outbox of the particular user.
Any ideas?
Thanks!
